# Navigation Component, Control when to show hamburger or back icon

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have the following Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var drawerLayout: androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

    drawerLayout = drawer_layout

    val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_main_navHost)

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)
    navView_main.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(drawerLayout,
        Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_main_navHost))
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

which as you can see is associated with navigation graph, and I am using a navigation drawer. When I am navigating through the items in the drawer I want to keep the hamburger icon, and only change it to up/back button when I click on an item within the fragment or popup for example and ensure that the behavior of the system reflects what the user expects based on the icon displayed. Is that possible

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To control when the AppBar navigation up/back show the following need to be done

1- create AppBarConfiguration and pass to it the top level destination and drawerLayout

```
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.dest_one,
            R.id.dest_two
        ),
        drawerLayout
    )
```

2- Tell the AppBar about the configration and navigation. this will help to show a title and show up arrow or drawer menu icon

```
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfig)
```

3- Finally override the onOptionsItemSelected and onSupportNavigateUp and the Navigation Component extension to inform the AppBar how to behave

```
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem)= item.onNavDestinationSelected(findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment))
        || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)


override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment).navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
```

Reference Google Code Lab Navigation [Navigation Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/index.html?index=..%2F..index#8)

Comment: I tried this code and defined all my top level destinations, but when i am moving from top level destination to one other fragment back button is shown ,when on clicking the toolbar's back button the drawer will open again. How can i solve this issue

Comment: Could you please share code snippet or something to see what you are doing

Comment: Could you share it on github and provide a link to it

Comment: Acttually i can raise it as another question and share the link.Is that ok?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219768/toolbars-back-button-not-working-when-using-with-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 11):

Follow this steps

**1.** Bind your [**`NavigationView`** with **`NavigationUI`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#setupWithNavController(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView,%20androidx.navigation.NavController))

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(nav_view, hostFragment.navController)
```

**2.** Bind  [**`ActionBar`** With **`NavController`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupActionBarWithNavController(android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity,%20androidx.navigation.NavController))

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this@NavActivity, hostFragment.navController)
```

**3.** Bind [**`ActionBar`**  and **`DrawerLayout`** With **`NavController`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#setupActionBarWithNavController(android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity,%20androidx.navigation.NavController,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout))

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this@NavActivity, hostFragment.navController, drawer_layout)
```

**4.** override  `onSupportNavigateUp()` in your activity

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(drawer_layout, hostFragment.navController) 
              || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

**Sample:**

```
class NavActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    lateinit var hostFragment: NavHostFragment

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        hostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment    
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(nav_view, hostFragment.navController)    
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this@NavActivity, hostFragment.navController)    
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this@NavActivity, hostFragment.navController, drawer_layout)    
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(drawer_layout, hostFragment.navController) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.nav, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> return true
            else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
}
```

---

## Output

#### Home Fragment:

[image: Home Fragment]

#### Fragment Two:

[image: Fragment Two]

#### Fragment Tree:

[image: Fragment Tree]

Comment: Thank you for trying, but what you have provided has steps that are not required, and has produced the same result. I should be able to control what icon I want to display when navigating using the navigation drawer.

Comment: in principle, the navigation drawer should have lateral navigation which means the items are at the same level. So when I am moving from one item to another using the drawer the fragment should be replaced not added on top of the stack. Please see https://material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html#lateral-navigation. One last thing, all you need is step three, and 4 if you want to have the arch component control the back and up behavior

Comment: When I click on back arrow, it displays navigation drawer instead of going back to previous fragment.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi haveu `override` the `onSupportNavigateUp()` method like in my above code

Comment: When I click on back arrow, it displays navigation drawer instead of going back to previous fragment. – Is there any solution for this,I am not looking for a work around

Comment: When I click on back arrow, it displays navigation drawer instead of going back to previous fragment. Just add  toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController)

Answer (score 3):

So, I think that you can use the **NavController.OnNavigatedListener** to listen wich fragment will be shown, and then update de toolbar icon.

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_main_navHost)
navController.addOnNavigatedListener(contoller, destination -> {
   if(destination.id == R.id.fragmentTwo){
          // change the toolbar icon here
}
    })
```

Sorry, I have no computer here, so I write this code without any IDE, this can have error. But take the idea.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Though your answer could be a workaround I was hoping for a solution that automates this process. This will require keeping track of the fragments to know which action to perform. With this I will lose the benefits of the Navigation Arch Component.