# Toolbars Back button not working when using with navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack

Below is the code

I have defined all my top level destinations with AppbarConfiguraion.

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    lateinit var navController: NavController
    lateinit var binding: MainActivityBinding
    lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        navController = findNavController(R.id.navigation)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.homeFragment,
                R.id.bulletinsFragment,
                R.id.serviceFragment,
                R.id.paymentsFragment,
                R.id.feedBackFragment,
                R.id.formsFragment,
                R.id.surveysFragment
            ),
            drawer_layout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(
            this, navController, appBarConfiguration
            )

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawer_layout,
            binding.toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()
        sideNV.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if ((drawer_layout as DrawerLayout).isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            (drawer_layout as DrawerLayout).closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            findNavController(R.id.navigation).navigateUp()
        }
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_service, R.id.nav_payments, R.id.nav_forms, R.id.nav_bulletins,
            R.id.nav_surveys, R.id.nav_feedbacks -> {
                navController.navigate(item.itemId)
            }
        }
        (drawer_layout as DrawerLayout).closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = findNavController(R.id.navigation).navigateUp()
}
```

When moving from the top level fragments to other  fragments the back arrow is shown but when on clicking it opens the drawer itself.  When on clicking the system back button it's working fine.

Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".home.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".home.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Comment: please register your parent activity name in your toolbar activity in Manifest.xml file when you register your activity using android:parent="parent_activity_name".

Comment: Didn't get you!

Comment: can you show me your manifest.xml ??

Comment: Yeah .I just updated it

Comment: can you define addToBackStack() of Fragment when you call it ?

Comment: Actually i am doing that using navGraph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    lateinit var navController: NavController
    lateinit var binding: MainActivityBinding
    lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        navController = findNavController(R.id.navigation)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.homeFragment,
                R.id.bulletinsFragment,
                R.id.serviceFragment,
                R.id.paymentsFragment,
                R.id.feedBackFragment,
                R.id.formsFragment,
                R.id.surveysFragment
            ),
            drawer_layout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(
            this, navController, appBarConfiguration
        )

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawer_layout,
            binding.toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()
        sideNV.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
        toolbar?.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            findNavController(R.id.navigation).navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if ((drawer_layout as DrawerLayout).isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            (drawer_layout as DrawerLayout).closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_service, R.id.nav_payments, R.id.nav_forms, R.id.nav_bulletins,
            R.id.nav_surveys, R.id.nav_feedbacks -> {
                navController.navigate(item.itemId)
            }
        }
        (drawer_layout as DrawerLayout).closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = findNavController(R.id.navigation).navigateUp()
}
```

i just changed my code and added toolbar NavigationOnClickListener and in that listener i just added **navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)**.Also there is  a slight change in the **onBackPressed()** as in my previous code it will not close the app even if we are at the last fragment in the stack

Comment: Thanks, `toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener{navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)}` did work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
  override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the following because the navigation will handle this for you

```
val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,
        drawer_layout,
        binding.toolbar,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    )
    drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()
    sideNV.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if ((drawer_layout as DrawerLayout).isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        (drawer_layout as DrawerLayout).closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    } else {
        findNavController(R.id.navigation).navigateUp()
    }
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_service, R.id.nav_payments, R.id.nav_forms, R.id.nav_bulletins,
        R.id.nav_surveys, R.id.nav_feedbacks -> {
            navController.navigate(item.itemId)
        }
    }
    (drawer_layout as DrawerLayout).closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
```

Comment: No,It won't work.How will i get control over the toggle button, how will we detect the click on each item?

Comment: This part of the navigation architecture component. Which should take care of the navigation. If you need to do something when the view/ fragment change you need to use on distinction change call back

Comment: I didn't get you can you please explain, coz i know it won't work and I tried removing the code .The result was obvious ,toggle was not working, not detecting click in navigation menu.

Comment: Please read https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui it has all the information about how this work